# Convert interface{} to struct in Golang

Tags: go, struct, interface

I am very new to Go and am trying to get my head around all the different types and how to use them. I have an interface with the following (which was originally in a json file):

```
[map[item:electricity transform:{fuelType}] map[transform:{fuelType} item:gas]]
```

and I have the following struct

```
type urlTransform struct {
        item string
        transform string
}
```

I have no idea how to get the interface data into the struct; I'm sure this is really stupid, but I have been trying all day. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decode the JSON directly to types you want instead of decoding to an `interface{}`.

Declare types that match the structure of your JSON data. Use structs for JSON objects and slices for JSON arrays:

```
type transform struct {
    // not enough information in question to fill this in.
}

type urlTransform struct {
    Item string
    Transform transform
}

var transforms []urlTransform
```

The field names must be [exported](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) (start with uppercase letter).

Unmarshal the JSON to the declared value:

```
err := json.Unmarshal(data, &transforms)
```

or

```
err := json.NewDecoder(reader).Decode(&transforms)
```

Comment: I'm getting error `cannot use value (type interface {}) as type []byte in argument to json.Unmarshal: need type assertion`. I tried `err := json.Unmarshal(data.([]byte), &transforms)` but now I'm getting `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not []uint8` :(

Answer (score 3):

From your response : `[map[item:electricity transform:{fuelType}] map[transform:{fuelType} item:gas]]`. 
As you can see here this is a an `array` that has `map` in it.

One way to get the value from this is :

```
values := yourResponse[0].(map[string]interface{}). // convert first index to map that has interface value.
transform := urlTransform{}
transform.Item = values["item"].(string) // convert the item value to string
transform.Transform = values["transform"].(string)
//and so on...
```

as you can see from the code above I'm getting the the value using map. And convert the value to the appropriate type in this case is `string`.

You can convert it to appropriate type like `int` or `bool` or other type. but this approach is painful as you need to get the value one bye one and assign it your your field struct.